# How to access integer index from String?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to exctract titles & headers from web pages,But i get only one element.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

import urllib2 
url = urllib2.urlopen("http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/")

content = url.read()
patFinderTitle = re.compile('')
listIterator = []

listIterator[:] = range(2,16)

soup2 = BeautifulSoup(content)

soup2.findAll("title")
print soup2.findAll("h1")




for i in soup2.findAll("title"):
  print titleSoup[i]

  print "\n"
```

I am getting the error in for loop ie.

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not Declaration
```

Comment: Where is the `titleSoup` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print all `title` tag, simply print `i`. (`i` is not an index. Each `title` element is assigned to `i` while iterating the `findAll` result):

```
for i in soup2.findAll("title"):
    print i
    print "\n"
```

Comment: thanks, But it prints only one Title,I want whole Titles from the page

Comment: @Prashant, There's only one `title` tag.

Comment: @Prashant, If you mean article titles, you'd better find `h1`, `h2` tags.

Comment: Actually i want to access all the headers from the webpages

Comment: suppose i want to access the headlines from the newspaper.

Comment: @Prashant, Did you try the code that I linked in the previous comment?

Comment: @Prashant, You original problem (`TypeError`) is solved. Isn't it? So, please accept the answer, and post a separated question if you have another question.